On the (alleged) ambiguity of "Fabricius a subsellis demisso capite discesserat" (Cic. Clu. 58)
Some Latinist scholars (e.g. Lavency (1986) and Longrée (2014), i.a.; see the full references at the bottom of this post) have noted that the following example from Cicero could in principle be ambiguous. For example, according to Lavency, the constituent in the ablative case demisso capite could in principle have two readings, each one having a slightly different interpretation: 1) the Ablative Absolute (AA) reading and 2) the Praedicativum reading.

Fabricius a subsellis demisso capite discesserat (Cic. Clu. 58)

Here is the description of the ambiguity in Lavency's (1986) terms (see my English translation below):

“L’expression demisso capite ferait figure d’un Ablatif absolu si, l’organisant en proposition commutable avec cum caput demisisset, le lecteur comprenait ‘Fabricius baissa la tête (dans la situation ainsi faite), il partit (la tête baissée ou non) (...) L’interpretation la plus obvie –Fabricius garde la tête baissée- repose sur un autre type de construction syntaxique: le paradigme de l’épithète détachée [aka Praedicativum: Mitomino], où contrairement à l’Ablatif absolu, ...”.


“The expression demisso capite would be an Ablative Absolute if, to the extent that this construction is allowed to be replaced by the subordinate clause cum caput demisisset, the reader came to interpret 'Having Fabricius lowered his head (...), he left (with his head down or not )' (...) The most obvious interpretation -Fabricius kept his head down- is based on another type of syntactic construction: the paradigm of the 'detached epithet' [aka Praedicativum: Mitomino], where unlike the Ablative Absolute, ...”.

NB: Longrée (2014), in turn, does not relate this ambiguity to the syntactic difference noted by Lavency (his mentor/professor) but rather to the fact that demisso is an eventive verbal participle in the AA reading and a stative adjectival participle in the Praedicativum reading (e.g. see this post for this important distinction inherent in Latin participles). In my opinion, Longrée's (2014) proposal is not incompatible with Lavency's (1986) one but to show this would deviate me from the particular question I'm interested in here.
According to Lavency, one should not mix/conflate the Ablative Absolute reading with the Predicativum one since they involve two different syntactic constructions, each of them having a different interpretation (but see Woodcock (1959: 34), who conflates these two readings into what he calls the "predicative" one). As rightly noted by Lavency, the second reading above -the Praedicativum one: 'with his head down'- is THE pragmatically relevant/prominent/natural one here, which is, for example, the one nicely captured by C.D. Yonge's (1856) translation: 'Caius Fabricius had slunk away from his seat with his head down'. Note that this translation is only compatible with an analysis where demisso capite is syntactically lower than an Ablative Absolute (AA). In contrast to Predicatives, AAs occupy a more peripheral/external syntactic position, the one where they can receive a propositional interpretation (e.g. the temporal one exemplified above). It seems natural to infer from Lavency's quote above that this peripheral/higher syntactic position of the AA could be the one occupied by the subordinate clause cum caput demisisset (but see Baños (1992) for some qualifications).
Here is my question: are there attested examples where the ambiguity described above by Lavency is not just "theoretical" but REAL? That is to say, are there attested examples where pragmatics allows both interpretations (the AA reading & the Praedicativum reading) as natural ones?

Footnote: I concur with Pinkster's (1982) point that capite operto in the following example is not an Ablative Absolute either (contra what is said by Bennet (1914: 368) and Szantyr (1965: 137-138)) but a Praedicativum. As noted by Pinkster, examples like the second one from Cicero, where the alleged AA  involuto capite is juxtaposed with the Predicativum soleatum, confirm that these examples do not involve an AA (despite the fact that there is an adjunct predication in the ablative case where capite is the subject and involuto is the predicate. So a more accurate definition of the Ablative Absolute construction is needed).

Invocat deos immortales ut sibi auxilium ferant manibus puris, capite operto
(Plaut. Am. 1093-1094)


te prodire involuto capite, soleatum (Cic. Pis. 13)

REFERENCES
Baños Baños, José Miguel (1992). "La distribución sintáctica entre cum histórico y ablativo absoluto en prosa clásica". Cuadernos de filología clásica: Estudios latinos n. 2: 57-84.
Bennett, Charles E. (1914). Syntax of Early Latin II, Boston (reprint Olms, Hildesheim, 1966).
*Lavency, Marius (1986). “Le paradigme syntaxique de l’Ablatif absolu”. In F. Decreus & C. Deroux (eds.). Hommages à Josef Veremans (Latomus, 193). 184-191. Bruxelles.
Longrée, Dominique (2014). “Demisso capite: ablatif absolu ou épithète détachée? Réflexions sur la description d’un syntagme à deux constituants obligatoires”. In C. Cabrillana & Ch. Lehmann (edd.). Acta XIV Colloqui Internationalis Linguisticae Latinae. 361-372. Madrid: Ediciones Clásicas.
Szantyr, Anton (1965). Lateinische Syntax und Stilistik. München: Beck.
Woodcock, E.C. (1959). A New Latin Syntax. London: Methuen.
*Marius Lavency was an eminent Belgian latinist who wrote a wonderful (and, indeed, very useful!) descriptive grammar of Latin (it is one of my favorite ones!):
Lavency, Marius (1985/1997, 2nd ed.). VSVS: Grammaire latine: Description du latin classique en vue de la lecture des auteurs. Leuven: Peeters Publishers. Lavency 1997.

Are these examples to be described as "ablatives-of-manner"--how somrehing is done e.g. "submissa voce" = "with a quiet voice"? An AA is used to state the circumstances under which an action takes place e.g. "puella spectante pater discessit" = "with the girl watching, the father departed".

@tony If you take a look at this paper by Pinkster (https://www.harmpinkster.nl/files/articles/Praedicativum1982.pdf  ), you'll see that these ablatives (e.g. your example submissa voce) fall under the category of "ablativus qualitatis". As noted by Woodcock (1959), some examples like capitibus opertis can have an attributive reading ('with covered heads') and a predicative one ('with their heads covered'). As noted by you, submissa voce can have an attributive reading ('with a quiet voice'). Perhaps the predicative reading would be more unusual in this case.

How would you interpret this from Seneca: Non timide itaque conponor ad illum diem, quo remotis strophis ac fucis de me iudicaturus sum; IMO this is an AA, but I guess many would disagree. it describes the settings/circumstances at the day of death rather than the manner which the judgment is passed - which (the later) is of course also a possible reading - which I believe Loeb has "putting aside all stage artifice and actor’s rouge, I am to pass judgment upon myself,"

@d_e I agree that the AA reading of your ex. is plausible. What I don't see is the connection of your example with my specific question about the ambiguity between the AA reading & the Praedicativum one: remotis strophis ac fucis cannot be (easily) interpreted as a Praedicativum (aka Secondary Predicate). The predicative constructions at issue here are those ones that can be coordinated with a Praedicativum: e.g. Pompeius [saucius] et [intorto talo] tardabatur ad fugiendum (Bell. Hisp. 39.1). Cf. also the plausibility of the ex. Fabricius [tristis] et [demisso capite] discesserat.
